# Configuring dynamic state in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, oclazyload

I need to configure dynamic state with dynamic template and url.

```
.state('s1.s2.:s3',{
        url: "/name",
        templateUrl: ["$stateParams",function($stateParams) {
                        return 'path/' + $stateParams.s3 + '.html';
                    }],
        resolve:{
            loadPlugin :["$ocLazyLoad","$stateParams", function($ocLazyLoad,$stateParams){
                return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                    name: $stateParams.name+"TemplatePage",
                    files : ['path/'+$stateParams.s3+'.js'] 
                }])
            }]
        },
        controller: $stateParams.s3 +'Controller',
    })
```

The state s3 would be dynamic. And based on the name(s3) I need to load the html and js file in the same name(s3). Is it possible to resolve?, I searched and came up with the above code but not sure how to do it.